# How to get page's HTML with android + chrome via mink?

Tags: android, appium, behat, mink, appium-android

I use Appium + Behat + Mink with Android Emulator 7.1.1.

I am trying to do it with

```
$this->getSession()->getPage()->getContent();
```

On MacOS + iOS emulator + safari everything is ok and I get my HTML, but on Android I get some strange XML (I don't even know what is this):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<hierarchy rotation="0">
<android.widget.FrameLayout index="0" text="" class="android.widget.FrameLayout" package="com.android.chrome" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,0][1080,1794]" resource-id="" instance="0">
<android.widget.LinearLayout index="0" text="" class="android.widget.LinearLayout" package="com.android.chrome" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,0][1080,1794]" resource-id="" instance="0">
<android.widget.FrameLayout index="0" text="" class="android.widget.FrameLayout" package="com.android.chrome" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,63][1080,1794]" resource-id="" instance="1">
```

Solution - https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/9690#issuecomment-346622943

Comment: https://appium.readthedocs.io/en/stable/en/advanced-concepts/hybrid/ ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you get source of `NATIVE_APP` context.

Try to switch context to `WEBVIEW` or smth similar and then call `getContent()`

[Appium PHP client example](https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/commands-yml/commands/context/set-context.yml#L47)

Comment: Tell me please how I can switch context to WEBVIEW?

Comment: Check official server docs: https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/commands-yml/commands/context/set-context.yml#L47